# why horizontal Scrolling done by jquery mobile is very slow in android phone?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have implemented a div with a image in it.initially the div has class div1. When a checkbox is checked I removed the class div1 from the div and added div2 using jquery mobile. But when I ran this project of android phone the vertical scrolling was working fine but the horizontal scrolling was really irritating. The horizontal scrolling was moving very little. It was moving as much as we get the movement by providing one click to the scroller on browser. I need a solution. Can any one help please ?

my html :

```
<div id="myDiv" class="div1">
<img id="img1" src="images/Desert.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.div1 {

margin-top:5px;
margin-left:0px;
border-width:5px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#000000;
overflow: scroll !important;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;


}

.div2 {
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:0px;
border-width:5px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#000000;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noted this before on firefox on any platform, where a browser-side option "smooth scrolling" was the cause.

I'm not sure if this is the reason in your case, but since I searched hours for this solution, it might help you too...